# Show that $H(x,y)=x^2y^4+x^4y^2-3x^2y^2+1 \geq0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to show that  $H(x,y)=x^2y^4+x^4y^2-3x^2y^2+1 \geq0$. Firstly, I analyzed the critical points and I found that the minimum value for $f(x,y)$. However, this procedure just shows that $f(x,y) \geq0$ locally. Is there any other way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AM-GM inequality gives:
$$ x^2 y^4 + x^4 y^2 + 1 \geqslant 3\sqrt[3]{x^2 y^4 \cdot x^4 y^2 \cdot 1} = 3\cdot x^2 y^2.$$

Comment: Thank you! I considered the AM-GM but I was doing it wrong

Comment: This is an interesting polynomial because, although it is never negative, it is not a finite sum of squares of real polynomials.

Comment: @user254665, how do you know? Proving that for a homogeneous polynomial may be difficult, do you have some simpler argument using the differing degrees of the terms in this example?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_seventeenth_problem

Comment: @user254665, I get it, this is the wikipedia example with $z=1:$  The formulation of the question takes into account that there are polynomials, for example[9]

  $$  f(x,y,z)=z^6+x^4y^2+x^2y^4-3x^2y^2z^2 $$ 

which are non-negative over reals and yet which cannot be represented as a sum of squares of other polynomials,

Comment: @user254665, particularly pages 398, 519 and 532 in Lam (2005) : http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=gsm-67

Comment: Proving that a non-negative polynomial $p : R^n \to R$ with $n>1$,  is a sum of squares  of rational functions,  was one of David Hilbert's famous problem set.